# Removing Duplicate entries in grub2 Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, grub, duplicate

I have made a custom grub2 menu however, both the default and the custom show together. So my grub looks like the list below, the bolded entries are my custom ones. How do I get rid of the duplicates? I have tried apt-get remove and deleting old kernels. I am a bit lost. Thanks! in Advance.

```
ubuntu,linux ...
ubuntu,linux recovery
memtest
memtest
windows7
windows7
ubuntu linux
ubuntu linux recover
```

I have tried apt-get remove I have tried marking and removing older kernels. This is how I made my custom grub by the way. I copied and pasted the grub.cfg menuentry code into the custom one and just renamed the titles so it would be perfectly clear for the user who doesn't want to know what version # it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to run "sudo update-grub2" after apt-get remove. Now it works.